# Redirect to new page without displaying parent page

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I want to redirect a page with link having #. Since value after # is not sent to server with HTTP request, I coded script as below in Razor view.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
if (window.location.hash) {
var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase().replace("ug_101", "UG");
window.location = url;
}
```

I placed the code at top of the page but still elements in parent view are rendered before redirecting. How to redirect without loading parent view? Or how to get the value after # in URL in C#?

Answer (score 0):

You put your code inside a `.ready()` function, so the jQuery isn't executed until the page is partially loaded.

Try it with your script looking like this:

```
if (window.location.hash) {
var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase().replace("ug_101", "UG");
window.location = url;
```

None of it is jQuery, and none needs any part of the page to load, so the `.ready()` method is causing your delay for no good reason.

Comment: Thanks. I tried the code 
   <script type="text/javascript">
   if (window.location.hash) {
   var url = window.location.href.toLowerCase().replace("ug_101", "UG");
   window.location = url;
   }
    </script>
But the page keeps on loading in Firefox. Not redirecting. In safari page is redirecting but still header in layout page is displayed before redirecting.

Comment: You could take it a step further and make it an empty page, redirecting to one page or the other.  You wouldn't see anything until you arrived at a page of content.  FYI, This is a job best done on the server because the page loading wile you're redirecting is going to be based on  your server's speed, the redirect target server's speed, the users Internet connection speed - all things that vary by user and are completely out of your control.  If the server does it (by some means besides the hash string) you'd redirect quick and simple.